# Mysql UNION or something else to get debit and credit totals for different accounts

Tags: mysql

Example, placed here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b4e73c/5 and
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af22/1

Have table `accounts` with list of accounts. And have table `transactions` with list of all transactions.

In `accounts` table are following accounts: 1210, 2380, 5310, 7720.

In `transactions` table are following transactions:

```
DebitAccount | CreditAccount | Amount 

1210         | 5310          | 10.5 

7720         | 2380          | 4.6
```

As result want to get array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [AccountCode] => 1210
        [DebitTotal] => 10.5
        [CreditTotal] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [AccountCode] => 5310
        [DebitTotal] => 0
        [CreditTotal] => 10.5
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [AccountCode] => 7720
        [DebitTotal] => 4.6
        [CreditTotal] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [AccountCode] => 2380
        [DebitTotal] => 0
        [CreditTotal] => 4.6
    )
```

If i select separately, like

```
SELECT 
`COA`.`AccountCode`, 
SUM(`JL`.`Amount`) AS `DebitTotal`
FROM `transactions` `JL` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` `COA` ON `JL`.`DebitAccount` = `COA`.`AccountCode`
GROUP BY `COA`.`AccountCode`;
```

Then all ok. But how to unify ?

Incorrect code is this

```
SELECT `AccountCode`, `DebitTotal`, `CreditTotal` 

FROM 

( 
SELECT 
`COA`.`AccountCode`, 
SUM(`JL`.`Amount`) AS `DebitTotal`
FROM `transactions` `JL` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` `COA` ON `JL`.`DebitAccount` = `COA`.`AccountCode`
GROUP BY `COA`.`AccountCode` 

UNION  

SELECT
`COA`.`AccountCode`, 
SUM(`JL`.`Amount`) AS `CreditTotal`
FROM `transactions` `JL` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` `COA` ON `JL`.`CreditAccount` = `COA`.`AccountCode`
GROUP BY `COA`.`AccountCode` 

) `TempTable`
```

Get error `Unknown column 'CreditTotal' in 'field list'`

Problem is that Debit and Credit account numbers may be not the same. I mean in Debit exists some account, but in Credit the account does not exist....

I tried to select all accounts from `accounts` table. Then php foreach all accounts and created long sql to select from `transactions` table. But seems that is a waste of resources... Trying to do all with one query.

Comment: Where is `AmountInMoney` in your tables?

Comment: Excuse me, error in column name. Must be `Amount `. I will correct

Comment: Here is updated (seems) working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8a57/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `CreditTotal` the third column in the second query in the `UNION`. Add empty columns to both subqueries for the sum in the other query.

```
SELECT AccountCode, SUM(Debit) AS DebitTotal, SUM(Credit) AS CreditTotal
FROM (
    SELECT DebitAccount AS AccountCode, Amount AS Debit, 0 AS Credit
    FROM transactions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CreditAccount AS AccountCode, 0 AS Debit, Amount AS Credit
    FROM transactions
) AS u
GROUP BY AccountCode
```

There's no need to join with `accounts`, since you're not using any columns from that table.

Comment: Thanks! Seems something works. At first got `Every derived table must have its own alias`, but before `GROUP BY AccountCode` added `AliasForTable` and seems all works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af22/5. Need to check... yes, actually i do not need from `accounts` table.. but need to check

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union approach here:

```sql
SELECT
    a.AccountCode,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Amount < 0 THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS DebitTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Amount > 0 THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS CreditTotal
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DebitAccount AS Account, -1.0*Amount AS Amount FROM transactions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CreditAccount, Amount FROM transactions
) t
    ON t.Account = a.AccountCode
GROUP BY a.AccountCode;
```

Comment: Got `Unknown column 't.Amount' in 'field list'` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af22/3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af22/8 `-1.0*Amount ` changed to `-1.0*Amount  AS Amount`. Only question regarding performance of these subselects....